# SetInterval missing property in js class

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote simple class in JS witch works, but i had problem when i try use setInterval with it. 
Ex. if i do something like that

```
ball = new ball(5,10,0, '#canvas');
ball.draw();
ball.draw();
ball.draw();
ball.draw();
```

It works. But this:

```
ball = new ball(5,10,0, '#canvas');
setInterval(ball.draw, 100);
```

Not work.
I get error that values are undefined.

```
function ball (x,y,z,holdingEl) {
    this.r = 5; //zmienna przechowujaca promien pilki
    this.size = this.r *2; // zmienna przechowujaca rozmiar
    this.ballSpeed = 100; // predkosc pilki
    this.ballWeight = 0.45; // masa pilki
    this.maxFootContactTime = 0.2; // maksymalny czas kontaktu pilki z noga - stala
    this.ctx = jQuery(holdingEl)[0].getContext("2d"); // obiekt pilki
    this.intVal = 100 // predkosc odswiezania
    this.currentPos = { // wspolrzedne pozycji
        x: x,
        y: y,
        z: z
    }
    this.interactionPos = { // wspolrzedne pozycji ostatniej interakcji
        x: -1,
        y: -1,
        z: -1
    }
    this.direct = { // kierunek w kazdej plaszczyznie
        x : 1,
        y : 0,
        z : 0
    }
    this.draw = function (){
      this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,1100,800);
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.arc(this.currentPos.x, this.currentPos.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
      this.ctx.closePath();
      this.ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error you get?

Comment: As a side note, if you're going to be creating multiple instances of `ball`, you should add the `draw` function to the `prototype` of `ball` so that it is shared between instances. Right now you're creating a redundant function for each instance.

Comment: `ball = new ball(...);` Aren't you overwriting the constructor function with the instance?

Comment: Yes my mistake in both cases, but... using prototype i can't use private variables or function for ex. funtion foo () { var private; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing it is because you're sending a reference to the function itself, which is not geting called from the context of `ball`.

Do this instead:

```
ball = new ball(5,10,0, '#canvas');
setInterval(function() {
    ball.draw();
}, 100);
```

Using your first code, within the `draw()` function, `this` is the `ball` instance.

Using your `setInterval()` code, `this` will be `window` in the `draw()` function.

Comment: Hmm... What about [`ball.draw.bind(ball)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)? I guess the problem there is that it's not widely supported yet...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ball = new ball(5,10,0, '#canvas');
f = function() {
 ball.draw()
}
setInterval(f, 100)
```